# Spock - setup spec with groovy trait and @BeforeClass

Tags: groovy, junit, traits, spock

I was trying to setup a common array of objects which are loaded and deserialised from json file in resources and tried to do this by using groovy trait with setup() method.

Trait:

```
Object[] arr

@BeforeClass
def setupTrait() {
   arr = loadFromFile("xxx.json")
}
```

Test:

```
def setup() {}

def "test"() {
   arr.size() //here arr is null, although the setup in groovy is called
}
```

---

Working solution.

Trait:

```
static Object[] arr = loadFromFile("xxx.json")
```

Test:

```
def setup() {}

def "test"() {
   arr.size() //here arr is ok.
}
```

The question is why the first isn't working right?
If I use @Before annotation and arr is loaded before each test, it's somehow working...

Comment: Thanks for your interesting question. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and always try to provide one. It would be much better than your incoherent set of snippets without class definitions, package names, imports etc. Everyone trying to reproduce your problem has to create their own  (possibly faulty) versions of your setup. Look at how Mark did it in his answer and learn from him and the article I linked to. Thank you.

Comment: ok, thank you for hints - I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some minor mistakes that I suggest to rewrite in a more "spock"-y way:

- in spock you're supposed to use `def setupSpec()` fixture method and not `@BeforeClass`
- if you want to initialize a variable in `setupSpec` that indeed will run only once for all test cases you are supposed to put `@Shared` annotation on the field.

But then, even if the code will look like this:

```
trait SampleTrait {
    @Shared List arr
    def setupSpec() {
        arr = [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

It still doesn't work. Now, It looks like you've encountered an open issue in spock:

https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/83

The issue is open, but the workaround exists and is suggested in the discussion: put a word static (you have actually done that :)). The reason: `@Shared` annotation cannot be processed by Spock when they appear in traits.

So, all-in-all I believe the best you can get is:

```
trait SampleTrait {
    static List arr

    def setupSpec() {
        arr = [1,2,3]
    }
}

class SampleTestSpec extends Specification implements SampleTrait {
    def "list equality"() {
        expect:
          arr == [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I've come to the same conclusion after tracking Spock docs and groovy open issues regarding @Shared annotation and problems with traits ;)